# Halfway point in a range of values

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to find the halfway in a range of values.

Using this data as an example: [image]

I need to sum the range (B1 to B10 = 17200), find the halfway point (8600) then find that halfway point in the range (Sum of B1 to B8 is 5700 leaving 2900 remaining till halfway, which in this case is 58% through Point 9 (2900/5000).

The values will change day to day as will the size of the range, eg it may only be B3 to B7 one day and B1 to B5 the next. The total size of the range can also be quite large, 10 was just used in the example.

Not sure if this is even possible.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're asking it's clear cut. Does that mean that with the sample data, you want to get Point 9? And what if the halfway was 8000? From what I understood, you would be leaving 5100 till halfway after B1 to B8 and 2% through Point 9. Would you still want to get Point 9 (assuming you indeed wanted point 9 in the initial example).

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  What should the final actual output be in your example?  Also, if we are looking from B1 to B10, why do we care about 58% to B9?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(SUM($B$1:$B1)/(SUM(B:B)/2)>1,IF(ROW($B1)>1,IF(100*(1-(((SUM(B:B)/2)*((SUM($B$1:$B1)/(SUM(B:B)/2))-1))/B1))>0,"Midpoint is " & INDIRECT("A" & VALUE(ROW(C1)-1)) & " + " &100*(1-(((SUM(B:B)/2)*((SUM($B$1:$B1)/(SUM(B:B)/2))-1))/B1)) & "% of " & $A1,"Too Much"),"Midpoint is " &100*(1-(((SUM(B:B)/2)*((SUM($B$1:$B1)/(SUM(B:B)/2))-1))/B1)) & "% of " & $A1),"Not Enough")
```

Place the formula above in Column C then fill down for the length for your list o values.

You will want to find the point where Column C stops saying "Not Enough"

The entry will look like: Midpoint is Point 8 + 58% of Point 9.

Additional rows after midpoint will show "Too Much"